# How to list users for a given account in Python in Google Analytics Management API?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

We are trying to start with Google Analytics Management API by running an example script in Python from the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/user-management

Unfortunately, it is not working and we receive a bug like:

[image]

It was sugested to add authorization to that script, so we use the code from:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py

like:

```
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users']
  key_file_location = '...'
  service_account_email= '...'

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, key_file_location,
    service_account_email)
```

But still the problem remains unsolved.

What is wrong? 
Is it the authorization process? But the HelloAnalytisc.py script is working and we can authorize and get data.

Our whole script is here:

```
"""A simple example of Google Analytics batched user permissions."""
import argparse

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import json
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest

def call_back(request_id, response, exception):
  """Handle batched request responses."""
  print (request_id)
  if exception is not None:
    if isinstance(exception, HttpError):
      message = json.loads(exception.content)['error']['message']
      print ('Request %s returned API error : %s : %s ' %
             (request_id, exception.resp.status, message))
  else:
    print (response)


def add_users(users, permissions):
  """Adds users to every view (profile) with the given permissions.

  Args:
    users: A list of user email addresses.
    permissions: A list of user permissions.
  Note: this code assumes you have MANAGE_USERS level permissions
  to each profile and an authorized Google Analytics service object.
  """

  # Get the a full set of account summaries.
  account_summaries = analytics.management().accountSummaries().list().execute()

  # Loop through each account.
  for account in account_summaries.get('items', []):
    account_id = account.get('id')

    # Loop through each user.
    for user in users:
      # Create the BatchHttpRequest object.
      batch = BatchHttpRequest(callback=call_back)

      # Loop through each property.
      for property_summary in account.get('webProperties', []):
        property_id = property_summary.get('id')

        # Loop through each view (profile).
        for view in property_summary.get('profiles', []):
          view_id = view.get('id')

          # Construct the Profile User Link.
          link = analytics.management().profileUserLinks().insert(
              accountId=account_id,
              webPropertyId=property_id,
              profileId=view_id,
              body={
                  'permissions': {
                      'local': permissions
                  },
                  'userRef': {
                      'email': user
                  }
              }
          )
          batch.add(link)

      # Execute the batch request for each user.
      batch.execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':

# Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users']
  key_file_location = '...'
  service_account_email='...'


  # Construct a list of users.
  emails = ['ona@gmail.com', 'emi@gmail.com', 'sue@gmail.com', 'liz@gmail.com']

  # call the add_users function with the list of desired permissions.
  add_users(emails, ['READ_AND_ANALYZE'])
```

Comment: http 403 is "forbidden". Is your service account added to the GA account with user management permissions ?

Comment: Yes, @EikePierstorff , it's added

Comment: We have just added our script. Have a look, please.

Comment: Per [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/authorization) *You will get a 403 status code if the authorized user does not have access to the view (profile). Make sure you are authorized with the correct user and that they indeed have the view (profile) you have selected.*